# Evernote Firefox Plugin Tagging Problem

Tags: firefox, plugins, evernote

I have a usability problem with the evernote firefox plugin (the standalone plugin, which is active when the evernote client is not installed on the underlying machine)

[ScreenShot http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1508092/publish/superuser-evernote-screenshot.jpg](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1508092/publish/superuser-evernote-screenshot.jpg)

In the above screenshot I am entering a new tag named "eve". There are also 2 tags in the system "evernote" and "evolution", which are offered in the dropdown.

There are other similar programs where such cases work nicely (e.g. the superuser.com interface) but in evernote I somehow don't get it.

When I type the last e of eve and after that a comma, the system thinks I want to use "evolution", which drives me nuts. Please correct me, what am I getting wrong here?

But I cannot find a nice way how to type the words I want (especially new tags that are contained in existing tags!) and not being interrupted by evernotes suggestions, because always the first suggestion is selected and used as soon as I type a comma or a return.

How can I use this nicely?

**Edit:** I am looking for a solution that only needs the keyboard and the best would be it works without looking at the screen (i just want to type many tags without interacting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit the <kbd>Del</kbd> key before pressing <kbd>,</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I didn't notice this problem with the Evernote Plug-in until you pointed it out. Now it bugs me too!

It looks like it's hardwired to place its suggestion in whenever a comma, space, or return key is pressed. The easiest workaround I can think of is to just use a period(.) or semicolon(;) rather than a comma, until all the tags are typed in, and then change them to commas. It's not convenient, but it works.